# Fields from custom nodes into Webform

Tags: nodes, entities, webforms

I have some nodes like this http://sprachzentrum.com.ar/cursos/curso-intensivo-de-alem%C3%A1n-nivel-a21-agosto-2011 and webforms and want to insert titel and day field as an option in the webform.

So that the user can choose from different levels

---

thanks of course! My question was: I have a node with an titel and some customer fields like level an time an I ask myself if its possible tu render the listbox automaticaly so that i will a options like:

1| [custom-field-level-1] [node-title-1] [custom-field-time-1]
2| [custom-field-level-2] [node-title-2] [custom-field-time-2]
3| [custom-field-level-3] [node-title-3] [custom-field-time-3]

So for each node from a certain type I will get an option on my webform

Comment: Which drupal version are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

For both level and date (I understand these are session, so a range of date), you can add some "select list" in order to let the user select between the available options.
Do you have troubles adding this ? Can you make your question a little clearer regarding what you want and what causes you difficulties ?
[image]

Select the "listbox" option and it will produce:

[image]

**Edit June, 23:**

- so you have a Content Type named "webform_info" with some fields "field_level" and "field_time".
- the idea is to implement a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) (in a custom module) to retrieve these fields and put them in the webform

```php
    <?php
    function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      //you need to set up a custom module to store this.
      //use devel with dsm($form); to figure the name of each field
      if ($form['#id'] == 'webform-client-form-123') {
        //delete the array of options from the webform field, they start by "con_"
        $form['submitted']['con_level']['#options'] = Array();
        $form['submitted']['con_level']['#options'][''] = '- Select one level/time -';
        $i = 1;

        //retrieve the nodes of the type webform_info
        $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE type = 'webform_info' AND status = 1");
        while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
          $node_level = node_load($row['nid']);
          $form['submitted']['con_level']['#options'][$i] = $node_level->field_level[0]['value'] . $node->title . $node_level->field_time[0]['value'];
          $i++;
        }
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Doing `node_load` can be pretty heavy if you have a great number of nodes, so you might want to use the CCK table structure, have a look at another [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5560/allow-users-to-edit-cck-allowed-values-list-for-select-list/5722#5722) to adapt the code.
Code is for D6 but should give you some insights to apply this to D7 if needed.

Comment: @Daniel, was what ? :)

Comment: My question was: I have a node with an titel and some customer fields like level an time an I ask myself if its possible tu render the listbox automaticaly so that i will a options like:

1| [custom-field-level-1] [node-title-1] [custom-field-time-1] 2| [custom-field-level-2] [node-title-2] [custom-field-time-2] 3| [custom-field-level-3] [node-title-3] [custom-field-time-3]

So for each node from a certain type I will get an option on my webform

Comment: @Daniel I edited my answer to give you some code.