# Allow users to edit the list of CCK allowed values for "select list"

Tags: entities, users

I have a CCK field ("City") that is a select list, and has manually entered cities in the allowed values list. I added these cities (as the administrator of the website) but I would like to hand control over to the client.
However, changing their permissions, and allowing them full access to the CCK content types would be potentially disastrous; I need a way to give authenticated users permission to add values to this select list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use taxonomy.

- Taxonomy has it's own permission system.
- Drupal adds a lot of nice features for taxonomies.
- Categories such as cities is a perfect match for a taxonomy.

Comment: I have already implemented this with CCK - I just need the added functionality for allowing users to add values. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @Garry My guess is that it would be simpler and more stable to re-create using taxonomy than to create an interface to manage this. It's the old tale about being 80% done.

Comment: Does taxonomy have enough granular permission to allow peoples only add terms to a certain vocabulary ?

Comment: @tostinni If you have an actual question ask it but not in comments, use the ask question link top right corner.

Comment: It is an actual question but I think the answer is crucial to this question and it can help your answer to be accepted or not ;). Personnaly without adequate permissions I would never allow normal users to create taxonomy terms.

Comment: @tostinni I would probably create a standalone form to keep users out of the admin interface anyways. A simple drupal_get_form should suffice.

Comment: Great, that will help @Garry to make up is mind.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module which does exactly this - allows regular users to edit CCK field values. The module is called 'values' (http://drupal.org/project/values).

Answer (score 0):

With CCK I would do the following:

- create a content type "cities" with a "cityname" field
- in the "City" field you defined, I would put some PHP code to populate the "allowed values" textarea:

  ```
  $cities = Array();
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE status = 1 AND type = 'cities'");
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
    $node_city = node_load($row['nid']);
    $cities[$node->nid] = $node_city->field_cityname[0]['value'];
  }
  return $cities;
  ```

A couple of remarks here:

- the code is for D6 but can be adapted quite easily I think.
- you'll have to put in place some validation in the creation of "cityname" to avoid duplicates (maybe also think about a country field).
- it can be quite heavy to load a big number of `$node_city`, personnaly I'd rather use the tables of CCK to query the value directly, it's a little more complicated but ligther.

  ```
  $cities = Array();
  $field = content_fields('field_cityname');
  $db_info = content_database_info($field);

  $result = db_query("SELECT n.nid, " . $db_info['columns']['value'] . " AS city
            FROM {node} n 
            INNER JOIN {'. $db_info['table'] . '} c ON c.vid = n.vid
            WHERE status = 1 AND type = 'cities'");
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
    $cities[$row['nid']] = $row['city'];
  }
  return $cities;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I've created [a (sandbox) module](http://drupal.org/sandbox/andy/1246072) that does what you want. I'd just like to reiterate that you might find taxonomy a better fit... but if you do want to continue the CCK route this module might help :)